# Catch whether user clicked previous or next month in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am writing custom code in the onChangeMonthYear event handler of the jQuery datepicker.  Is there a way I can determine whether the user clicked prev or next on the month buttons?  Initial options look a bit like this

```
dpOpts = { dateFormat: dpDisplayFormat,
        beforeShowDay: setSelectable,
        beforeShow: handleBeforeShow,
        onChangeMonthYear: handleMonthYearChange,
        ...}
```

and in my handleMonthYearChange I'd like to access `window.event.target.id` or some other property of `inst` that tells me in which direction the user is winding the calendar.  I tried an inline call so that I could manually pass in the event, but the inline function doesn't have direct access to the year and month arguments.

Any ideas?

Merci d'avance :)
Mark

Comment: what if you save the initial date and compare it when `onChangeMonth..` occurs?

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yup, that did cross my mind but I was hoping for some kind of built-in flag along the lines if isNavNext or isNavPrev :-(  Looks like I'll have to run with a straight comparison for now.. unless there's a way to access the window event from inside the onChangeMonthYear handler.